# How to clear custom notification when I click on remoteview or the action buttons?

Tags: android, notifications

[This is my notification remote View and when I click on notification it will not clear.Please provide some solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTNyl.png)

Comment: set a flag to ur notification
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Answer (score 1):

Use the flag Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);

// Cancel the notification after its selected

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

and to launch the app:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Create a new intent which will be fired if you click on the 

    notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, App.class);

// Attach the intent to a pending intent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the notification will be closed after the user clicks on it, you can specify this flag in the notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //other flags
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Other option would be canceling the notification through code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

just set a flag

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CONSTANT_MOTION_NOTIFICATION);

```
    final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context contextr, Intent intent) {
            Intent mute = new Intent(contextr, VideoActivity.class);
            mute.putExtra("url", "http://dev.galaxyweblinks.com/memorybadge/phase1/uploads/video/garage.mp4");
            contextr.startActivity(mute);
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
        }
    };
    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Create a Local broad cast receiver  onReceive call the desire activity and call cancelAll() from notificationmanager